# Visual Studio 2015 designer doesn't want to display the form - Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, designer

My visual studio designer drives me crazy, I get the following error :
InvalidArgument=Value of '10' is not valid for 'SplitterWidth'.
In my form.Designer.cs I searched for all the occurences of SplitterWidth, I did not found even one ! and it keeps on saying me that the value for SplitterWidth is not valid 
I deleted my bin and obj folders without any positive results.

If anybody has an idea about the origin of this issue or has already faced to a similar problem I will appreciate his help.

Comment: It could just be the default value.  Which is 4 but gets multiplied by the scaling factor.  Suggesting you have a high resolution monitor operating at ~250% scaling.  Such monitors often cause layout problems.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, I working with a laptop which has really hi res and a standard large screen - Thank you . In fact I found another way , bad one, I forced to design and fixed the damages manually, but I could not wait, must go ahead so ..

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with VS2019 after plugging my laptop back into the docking station and having Windows 10 decide to re-arrange all the windows.  The only way I was able to recover was to search for "dpiscaling" in the start menu, select "advanced scaling options", and disabling "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" and setting "Custom Scaling" on the same screen to 100%.  And then logging out and back in.  Then designer would let me open my very complex form.